# No internet Calling account Error

Tags: android

I posted this on Google Groups figure I would do as well here and see if I can get more play one the question:

I'm writing a piece of code that has a error every time I run it stating: 
-No internet calling account availible

I'm wondering if there is some kind of permissions involved in this or something else I am missing.

there be the code!

```
    case R.id.loadBtnWidgetConfig:
        someData = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
        String dataReturned = someData.getString("sharedString", "Can't Load....Sorry!");
        dataResults.setText(dataReturned);
        break;
```

And there is the cat of logs

```
07-28 16:51:45.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2249): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-28 16:51:45.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2249): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-28 16:51:45.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at this.file.app.Settings.onClick(Settings.java:49)
07-28 16:51:45.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
07-28 16:51:45.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
07-28 16:51:45.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-28 16:51:45.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-28 16:51:45.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-28 16:51:45.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-28 16:51:45.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-28 16:51:45.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-28 16:51:45.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
07-28 16:51:45.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
07-28 16:51:45.189: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: From [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), "We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of **source code** in them", also if you're app crashes you should always post your logcat errors. Sometimes we can take a blind guess and answer a question, but most of the time we need context to understand what is happening.

Comment: @Sam Here I added the code I am having trouble with and the logcat behind it

Comment: As you see there's a NPE in Settings.java on line 49, what line is this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the AndroidManifest.xml you must declare permissions. If you are using eclipse you can go to the permissions tab and add it that way or here is an xml statement that will get you going:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Not quite what we are looking for... I'm trying to get rid of the error and it is still persisting...

Comment: If you are sure that your code is correct then just either delete the error with the context menu or suppress errors in your project. Otherwise you can try this: go to Settings; Call; Use Internet Calling; and select the middle option: Only for Internet calls.

Comment: Again Brilliant effort, but My phone does not have the options for that which is 10x the strange level if you ask me.. I tried to implement the the suggested patch via the permission however that still brings up the issue at hand.

Comment: Interesting, well gave it my best effort :D goodluck. 10/10 would up vote if I could.